# Error installing hmm

Tags: python, hmmlearn

I am getting the following error installing hmm. I am not able to understand howto solve this.Please provide some solution. I have all the necessary prerequisites

```
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\hmmlearn
cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\vibhuti\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\users\vibhuti\anaconda3\include -Ic:\users\vibhuti\anaconda3\include /Tchmmlearn/_hmmc.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\hmmlearn/_hmmc.obj -O3

error: Command "cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\vibhuti\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\users\vibhuti\anaconda3\include -Ic:\users\vibhuti\anaconda3\include /Tchmmlearn/_hmmc.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\hmmlearn/_hmmc.obj -O3" failed with exit status 127

Failed building wheel for hmmlearn
Running setup.py clean for hmmlearn
Failed to build hmmlearn
Installing collected packages: hmmlearn
Running setup.py install for hmmlearn ... error
Complete output from command c:\users\vibhuti\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='C:\Users\Vibhuti\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e43n98hp\hmmlearn\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Vibhuti\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-jzs40nue\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hmmlearn
copying hmmlearn\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hmmlearn
copying hmmlearn\hmm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hmmlearn
copying hmmlearn\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hmmlearn
copying hmmlearn_init_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hmmlearn
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hmmlearn\tests
copying hmmlearn\tests\test_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hmmlearn\tests
copying hmmlearn\tests\test_gaussian_hmm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hmmlearn\tests
copying hmmlearn\tests\test_gmm_hmm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hmmlearn\tests
copying hmmlearn\tests\test_multinomial_hmm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hmmlearn\tests
copying hmmlearn\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hmmlearn\tests
copying hmmlearn\tests_init_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\hmmlearn\tests
running build_ext
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
building 'hmmlearn._hmmc' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\hmmlearn
cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\vibhuti\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\users\vibhuti\anaconda3\include -Ic:\users\vibhuti\anaconda3\include /Tchmmlearn/_hmmc.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\hmmlearn/_hmmc.obj -O3

error: Command "cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\\users\\vibhuti\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-pac
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the link `https://pypi.org/project/hmmlearn/` to follow the instructions for installing hmmlearn module in python.

Comment: i did that but there is a problem with setup.py that prevents it from running